# Get page dimensions and footer using windows GDI with c++

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

Using GDI print functions and a HDC variable, how can I get the printing page area and print a footer?

I'm aware first is necessary to calculate margins, like this:

```
margins.left   = MulDiv(rcMargin.left,   GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSX), 1000);
margins.top    = MulDiv(rcMargin.top,    GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY), 1000);
margins.right  = MulDiv(rcMargin.right,  GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSX), 1000);
margins.bottom = MulDiv(rcMargin.bottom, GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY), 1000);
```

Then calculate margin adjustment:

```
int iLeftAdjust   = margins.left  - iPhysOffsetX;
int iTopAdjust    = margins.top   - iPhysOffsetY;
int iRightAdjust  = margins.right - (iPhysWidth  - iPhysOffsetX - GetDeviceCaps(hDC, HORZRES));
int iBottomAdjust = margins.right - (iPhysHeight - iPhysOffsetY - GetDeviceCaps(hDC, VERTRES));
```

And then the width and height in device units:

```
iWidth  = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, HORZRES) - (iLeftAdjust + iRightAdjust);
iHeight = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, VERTRES) - (iTopAdjust + iBottomAdjust);
```

I've found some information [here](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/introduction-printing), but no details about printing a footer (using TextOut).

Thanks.

Comment: What part of `TextOut` don't you understand? The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145133%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is pretty clear.

Comment: My problem is not TextOut. I'm having trouble to figure how to put a footer in a page for printing (using PrintDlg).

Comment: Windows doesn't know beans about headers or footers, it only knows the paper size.  Where you put your foot on the page is entirely up to you, as long as it is with the paper bounds.